# ERROR in ./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0" and I've isntalled it with this code `npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0` But now it is showing this error message:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Website\<my file directory>\node_modules\react-router-dom\dist\index.js'
```

So, now what can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: *Where* did you install the `react-router-dom` package? What did you do to produce this error? It looks like you tried building something? You should ensure you are in the React project's root directory when installing project dependencies, and you'll probably also want to save the package to your project's package.json file by running `npm install --save react-router-dom@5.2.0`.